# What are CLOSE_WAIT and TIME_WAIT states?

Tags: windows, networking, port, tcpip

When I do `netstat -a` on my Windows machine, I get a listing of the ports with one of the four states:

```
- LISTENING
- CLOSE_WAIT
- TIME_WAIT
- ESTABLISHED
```

What do `CLOSE_WAIT` and `TIME_WAIT` mean/indicate?

Comment: See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/22946

Comment: see 'man netstat', scroll down to the state section: http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Comment: [Shameless plug](http://serverfault.com/questions/450055/lot-of-fin-wait2-close-wait-last-ack-and-time-wait-in-haproxy) to an answer on our sistersite [SF].

Comment: Cross site dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/538443/whats-the-difference-between-port-status-listening-time-wait-close-wait

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Due to the way TCP/IP works, connections can not be closed immediately.  Packets may arrive out of order or be retransmitted after the connection has been closed.

- **CLOSE_WAIT** indicates that the remote endpoint (other side of the connection) has closed the connection.
- **TIME_WAIT** indicates that local endpoint (this side) has closed the connection.

The connection is being kept around so that any delayed packets can be matched to the connection and handled appropriately.  The connections will be removed when they time out within four minutes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol for more details.

Comment: But isnt this mean that, even if the packets arrive after function returned, they would be still discarded by the application?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Packets that arrive out of order after the connection has been closed will be handled by the network stack.  These can be usually be safely discarded according to normal duplicate packet rules.   Packets that appear to be related to an unknown active connection are normally discarded, and generate a response.  The WAIT states protect against this traffic.

Comment: @BillThor: Are all these states included by ServerLimit or MaxRequestWorkers in Apache?

Comment: @mahmood Connections in the TIME_WAUT states are connections Apache has closed. Connections in CLOSE_WAIT state will be handled by Apache until it is read, which should be almost immediately after the connection was closed. These connections will not be included in ServerLibm or MaxRequestWorkers. To verify run the command "netstat -antp | grep WAIT".

Comment: @BillThor: Thanks. Honestly, I didn't expect an answer after all these years... I want to be sure that current connections are below the ServerLimit. Still I don't know which states have to be counted. Should I check only ESTABLISHED? Or others such as SYN_RECV?

Comment: @mahmood Rather than trying to select states, I would exclude WAIT staties. Some states may indicate that a new connection is waiting to be accepted by Apache, so you may see more connections than Apache is handling.  This may require reconfiguration or DOS attack mitigation.

Comment: TIME_WAIT indicates that *both* ends have closed the connection. The system is not waiting to process any further packets, it is waiting for them to expire. Any further packets that come in are either duplicates or protocol errors.

Answer (score 37):

Basically the "WAIT" states mean that one side closed the connection but the final confirmation of the close is pending.

See e.g. this diagram of TCP states for details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg

Comment: This accurately describes CLOSE_WAIT but not TIME_WAIT. TIME_WAIT indicates that the local application closed the connection, and the other side acknowledged and sent a FIN of its own. We're now waiting for any stray duplicate packets that may upset a new user of the same port.

Comment: @ChrisSmowton, So who is using the right terminology? The diagram or `netstat`? ([cf.](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html))

Comment: @Pacerier I think they match -- where do you think they disagree?

Comment: @ChrisSmowton So this means next port owner may get extra bytes and that can break the response if we set TIME_WAIT = 0 ?

Comment: Possible but very unlikely, as the sequence numbers would need to match for the application to see the rogue packet spliced into the stream, or the receiver would need to buffer the apparently out of order packet until the right sequence number came around. I don't know enough about practical implementations to tell you whether the latter is done in practice.

Answer (score 2):

TIME_WAIT represents waiting for enough time to be sure that remote TCP received the ACK of its FIN request. See 
[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (and also RFC 793)

Comment: What does this add to the information provided by the existing answers?

Comment: Adds a reference to RFC 793

Comment: Wikipedia wrong again. It is waiting for packets to expire.